# Scientific notation with bigDecimals and decimalFormat

Tags: java, bigdecimal, decimalformat

I'm trying to display fractional numbers in scientific notation format using bigdecimals and decimalFormat and this is what I came up with so far:

```
 BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0.000001");
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0###E0");
 System.out.println(df.format(a));
```

This program outputs "1.0E-4", and that's exactly what I want. Now if I set the bigDecimal to be "0.2222" for example, the output is 2.222E-1.

My question is: is there any way to prevent the scientific notation in this case so instead of 2.222E-1, the output should be 0.2222?

Comment: You can choice the format you want based on the range of values. e.g. (a >= 0.1 ? ... : ...)

Comment: what are the cases in which you want to print the one format and not the other?

Comment: in the case of 0.0001, the format should be 1.0E-4. And in the case of 0.2222, the format should stay 0.2222 not 2.222E-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `String.format` with the `g` format specifier.  Documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dndec).

Here's some example code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class BigDecTest {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0.000001");
        System.out.println(String.format("%6.4G",a));

        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.2222" );
        System.out.println(String.format("%6.4G", b));
    }
}
```

It produces:

```
1.000E-06
0.2222
```

Comment: Thank you very much Schtever, that exactly what I needed.

Comment: @ToniJoe You're welcome!  Could I trouble you to accept my answer?